# Agregate functions and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I am working on some queries, and got to the point where I wanted to output average salary of employees, that are under management of certain manager. I found out, that if I use AVG, the path is not showing up.

Is it right, that SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH does not work with agregate functions?

Comment: Please show us your current query, along with sample data, curent and desired results.

Comment: For the problem as you described it, why do you even need SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH? If you do need it, then you didn't explain the problem very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate numeric values and you can do it alongside a hierarchical query with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

For example:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( name ) AS top_manager,
       SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( name, ' -> ' ), 5 ) AS management_chain,
       salary,
       AVG( salary ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) ) AS avg_salary
FROM   employees
START WITH id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = manager_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( id, name, manager_id, salary ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', NULL, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 1,    15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 2,    10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Darby', 1,    10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Ellen', 4,    25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Fiona', NULL,  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TOP_MANAGER | MANAGEMENT_CHAIN        | SALARY | AVG_SALARY
> :---------- | :---------------------- | -----: | ---------:
> Alice       | Alice                   |     20 |         16
> Alice       | Alice -> Betty          |     15 |         16
> Alice       | Alice -> Darby -> Ellen |     25 |         16
> Alice       | Alice -> Darby          |     10 |         16
> Alice       | Alice -> Betty -> Carol |     10 |         16
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=463215ed5df1d0db91d6c0b65c1cedb0)*

Comment: You don't even need to partition the AVG analytic function - if you START WITH exactly one ID, that will be the "root" for all rows. Meaning, even `avg(salary) over ()` will do.

Comment: True, but you can change to `START WITH manager_id IS NULL` (which is what I started with before it got edited to match the OP's "under management of a certain manager" requirement) and the query will still work and then you do want the `PARTITION`.